# How to set ItemDelegate to only apply to parent column in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I am inserting QComboboxes into the first column of a QTreeView as follows.

```
view->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, new ComboBoxDelegate(view));
```

The nodes in the 0th column have children, who (if i'm not mistaken) are also part of column "0". Therefore the comboboxes also appear there. How can I prevent the Comboboxes from appearing in the child branch?

What I have now:

```
>Combobox1
     Combobox2
```

How I want it to look: (Where "text" depends on index of combobox)

```
>Combobox1
     Text
```

Here are some of the functions that create the combobox:

```
ComboBoxDelegate::ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent): QItemDelegate(parent){
}


QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const{

    QComboBox *editor = new QComboBox(parent);
    editor->addItem("Run");
    editor->addItem("Run with SM");
    editor->addItem("Kinetic Run");
}
 return editor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is user the `QModelIndex &index` parameter to get the row, and then say something like:

```
if (!index.parent().isValid()) {
     //draw combobox
}
else {
     //don't draw
}
```

Comment: 1. I think it should be `if (!index.parent().isValid())` 2. `new` is not a problem here, the view will take ownership of the editor and delete it when no longer needed (or rather: it will call `destroyEditor` on the delegate, that calls `deleteLater` by default)

Comment: thank you for your response. the problem with this is that the first cell in the parent and the first cell in the child branch both have index (0,0). So using rows to distinguish between child and parent doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @king_nak you were right! It works as intended. Thanks!